# How to replace a character in some specific word in a text file using python

Tags: python, replace

I got a task to replace "O"(capital O) by "0" in a text file by using python. But one condition is that I have to preserve the other words like Over, NATO etc. I have to replace only the words like 9OO to 900, 2OO6 to 2006 and so on. I tried a lot but yet not successful. My code is given below. Please help me any one. Thanks in advance

```
import re

srcpatt = 'O'
rplpatt = '0'
cre = re.compile(srcpatt)

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()

wordlist = re.findall(r'(\d+O|O\d+)',str(content))
print(wordlist)

for word in wordlist:
    subcontent = cre.sub(rplpatt, word)
    newrep = re.compile(word)
    newcontent = newrep.sub(subcontent,content)

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(newcontent)

print('"',srcpatt,'" is successfully replaced by "',rplpatt,'"')
```

Comment: is `wordlist` coming out OK? If that much of it works we can focus on the rest.

Comment: do you have toreplace `O123` with a leading `0` -> `0123`

Comment: 'wordlist' just for seeing the output @Brian. Thanks for edit.

Comment: As you'll see - regex are easy to get wrong. "And so on" is no substitute for having a bunch more testcases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.sub` can take in a replacement function, so we can pare this down pretty nicely:

```
import re
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(re.sub(r'\d+[\dO]+|[\dO]+\d+', lambda m: m.group().replace('O', '0'), content))
```

Comment: This will not work for the string "9OO". You could change `\d+O+\d+` to `\d+O+\d*`.

Comment: yea thanks a lot! But what about the string like O4:O5 to 04:05 ?

Comment: Edited the regex, should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get away with matching just a leading digit followed by `O`. This won't handle `OO7`, but it will work nicely with `8080` for example. Which none of the answers here matching the trailing digits will. If you want to do that you need to use a lookahead match.

```
re.sub(r'(\d)(O+)', lambda m: m.groups()[0] + '0'*len(m.groups()[1]), content)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

srcpatt = 'O'
rplpatt = '0'
cre = re.compile(srcpatt)
reg = r'\b(\d*)O(O*\d*)\b'

with open('input', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        while re.match(reg,line): line=re.sub(reg, r'\g<1>0\2', line)
        print line

print('"',srcpatt,'" is successfully replaced by "',rplpatt,'"')
```